# how to make sure my MANIFEST.in file is being read by setup.py when using pip install

Tags: python, git, pip, manifest

***`myproj`***

```
├── myproj
│   ├── data_directory
│   │   ├── data1.dat
│   │   └── data2.dat
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── module1.py
│   └── module2.py
├── MANIFEST.in
└── setup.py
```

I have a python package named `myproj` that resides on our internal gitlab server.  I'm installing it via pip with a command similar to this:

```
pip install git+ssh://git@gitlab.domain.com/folder/myproj.git
```

This is successful in that it clones the repository and run's `setup.py`.  However, I tried to put

```
include myproj/data_directory/*
```

in the `MANIFEST.in` file to make sure all of my data files came for a ride.  It didn't work.  The [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/sourcedist.html) I've read show running `setup.py` on the command line with parameters such as this

```
python setup.py sdist --manifest-only
```

I don't think that's what gets run when I do `pip install`.

***Question(s)***

- What parameters do I need in my `MANIFEST.in` file to grab the files in `data_directory`?
- Where does the `MANIFEST.in` file need to be in relation to my package?
- What do I need to do to ensure that this installs properly using `pip`?

***Reference***
In case my `setup.py` is important

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(name='myproj',
      version='0.1',
      description="My project",
      author='me',
      author_email='me@example.com',
      packages=find_packages(),
      )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put it in the correct directory.

```
├── myproj
│   ├── data_directory
│   │   ├── data1.dat
│   │   └── data2.dat
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── module1.py
│   └── module2.py
├── MANIFEST.in
└── setup.py
```